# Microsoft Ribbon for WPF: Controling Item Count in QuickAccess Toolbar?

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

I am getting up to speed on the new [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en). I am creating a Ribbon with a Quick Access Toolbar. I have six items in the QAT--I'd like to show four of them and put the other two in the overflow button. At this point, all six buttons are showing, with no overflow button. How do I set the number of visible QuickAccess buttons? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per current development is concerned, I think IsOverflowItem is Readonly. So you dont have the ability to specify for the item to be Overflown or not. It depends totally on how much space you have for the buttons. If you resize the window a bit smaller, you might eventually see the buttons being automatically populated in the menu as the menu will be dynamically created.

So based on the current implementation, you can only specify

```
<ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar IsOverflowOpen="True">
```

to make sure that the QuickAccessToolbar overflows when there is no room for the button.

I wrote an article on Ribbon Control which might help you a bit. Take a look
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/introducing-ribbon-ui-control-for-wpf.html

Thanks.